# Symfony Ajax searchbar with Elasticsearch

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, elasticsearch, search

I want to use Elasticsearch in my Project. I have the following code:

**SearchController**

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/elasticsearch" )
 */
public function viewElasticsearch(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->get('term');

    if (empty($query)) {
        return new JsonResponse([]);
    }

    if (substr($query, -1) !== '*') {
        $query .= '';
    }

    $finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.app.product');
    $products = $finder->find($query);

    foreach ($products as $entity) {
        $result['results'][] = [
            'id' => $entity->getId(),
            'text' => $entity->getName(),
            'sku' => $entity->getSku(),
        ];
    }

    return new JsonResponse($result);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    $('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
        ajax: {
            url: '/product/api/elasticsearch',
            dataType: 'json',
            width: 'resolve', // need to override the changed default
            minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
            dropdownCssClass: 'select2-hidden',
            }
    });
</script>
```

If I call a search query through the command line :

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/app/product/_search?q=*iphone*&size=500'
```

I get 381 results from the search above, but if I do the same search from Symfony I get 8 results. How can I do a wildcard search in Symfony ?

Comment: What will the `dump($query)` show right after you get it from the request? I wonder if it is not the case of the query being urlencoded.

Comment: @MichałTomczuk the dump is "Iphone".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The finder of Elastichsearch is showing 10 results by default. If you want to change it you have to add a second parameter to the find method with a value you want. In my case I want to show 500 results.

```
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.app.product');
$products = $finder->find($query, '500');
```